# DocuSign API Create Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Currently I am using #DocuSignAPI to create envelope in which API required x and y position to add signature from recipients.
So my requirement is like if i upload the document it should be redirect to the Docusign UI where recipient would login and sign the document.
So the thing is instead of creating rest call via API.
I need some api where Docusign is going to handle by its way so i do not need to create UI for that which is very complex to build from my side.
Anyone can help me with is will be really great.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The UI in your qs is a tagging screen, this screen is for tagging the DocuSign tabs (from left hand side) on the document, and this tagging is normally done by Sender of an envelope, so do you want an API to direct your sender to this UI? whereas in your qs, you are also saying that you want a UI where recipient would login and sign the document, this UI is called Signing screen and you cannot create this UI, it is done by DocuSign, and when you send an envelope to a recipient, they will receive an email from DS to complete the signing ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this DocuSign recipe: [Sign from Your App](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app).

This sample (and many others) are available on the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center), along with tons of documentation about various integration scenarios and API reference.